# Airflow worker does not have any annotation on kubernetes executor

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am running airflow 1.10.10 on an EKS cluster and I am using kubernetes executor.
When the scheduler creates a new worker, the pod created does not have any annotation.

So my question is : how to set specific annotations for pod workers ? is there any option to set in airflow.cfg file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research, it seems that we can achieve this by adding the following to `airflow.cfg` file:

```
[kubernetes_annotations]
# The Key-value annotations pairs to be given to worker pods.
# Should be supplied in the format: key = value
```

Comment: Hey @hichamx did you find any solution? I have this
`[kubernetes_annotations]`


`# The Key-value annotations pairs to be given to worker pods.`

`# Should be supplied in the format: key = value`

`sidecar.istio.io/inject = "false"`

in my `airflow.cfg` but worker pods still don't get it.

Comment: Hey @eduartua, You can add annotations you want like : `myAnnotaion = myValue`